# Month and year filter in react - how to apply both at same time

Tags: reactjs, filter

As I just started to learn React I learn by modifying and adding functionality to my learning app.
I have a list of items with "ID, title, number and date", so I want to filter them by date. Date consist of year, month and day - I want to filter by year, month or both. My year and month filters works a-ok, but when I try to apply both filters at once, it does not work (always filter by one only). Relevant part of code below:
(btw sorry for my bad english :P )

```
function Expenses(props) {
  const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] =
    useState("2023");
  const filterChangeFilterYear = (selectedYear) => {
    setFilteredYear(selectedYear);
  };

  const filteredExpensesYear = props.items.filter((expense) => {
    if (filteredYear > 0) {
      return expense.date.getFullYear().toString() === filteredYear;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });


    const [filteredMonth, setFilteredMonth] =
      useState("12");
    const filterChangeFilterMonth = (selectedMonth) => {
      setFilteredMonth(selectedMonth);
    };
  
    const filteredExpensesMonth = props.items.filter((expense) => {
      if (filteredMonth < 12) {
        return expense.date.getMonth().toString() === filteredMonth;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpensesFilterYear
          selected={
            filteredYear
          }
          onChangeFilter={filterChangeFilterYear}
        />
        <ExpensesFilterMonth
          onChangeFilter={filterChangeFilterMonth}
        />
        <ExpensesChart expenses={(filteredExpensesMonth && filteredExpensesYear)} /> <--- this part does not work
        <ExpensesList items={(filteredExpensesYear && filteredExpensesMonth)} /> <--- this part does not work
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and less important part:

```
function ExpensesFilterYear(props) {

  const dropdownChangeHandler = (event) => {
    props.onChangeFilter(event.target.value);
 
  };

  return (
    <div className='expenses-filter'>
      <div className='expenses-filter__control'>
        <label>expenses for year:</label>
        <select value={props.selected} onChange={dropdownChangeHandler}> 
          <option value='0'>all</option>
          <option value='2022'>2022</option>
          <option value='2023'>2023</option>
          <option value='2024'>2024</option>
          <option value='2025'>2025</option>
          {/* <option value='2025'>2025</option> */}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  };

export default ExpensesFilterYear;
```

```
function ExpensesFilterMonth(props) {
  const dropdownChangeHandler = (event) => {
    props.onChangeFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="expenses-filter">
      <div className="expenses-filter__control">
        <label>month:</label>
        <select
          value={
            props.selected 
          }
          onChange={dropdownChangeHandler}
        >

          <option value="12">all</option>
          <option value="0">jan</option>
          <option value="1">feb</option>
          <option value="2">Mar</option>
          <option value="3">may</option>
          <option value="4">apr</option>
          <option value="5">jun</option>
          <option value="6">jul</option>
          <option value="7">aug</option>
          <option value="8">sep</option>
          <option value="9">oct</option>
          <option value="10">nov</option>
          <option value="11">dec</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExpensesFilterMonth;
```

as I have little experience I only did try to change && to ,. No idea what else to try

Comment: Try changing `const filteredExpensesMonth = props.items.filter` to `const filteredExpensesMonth = filteredExpensesYear.filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to run the second filter operation on the result of the first filter operation:

Change:

```
const filteredExpensesMonth = props.items.filter(...)
```

to:

```
const filteredExpensesMonth = filteredExpensesYear.filter(...)
```

---

You can make this slightly more efficient by combining both the filter operations, but the code will be a bit more complex:

```
const filteredExpensesMonth = props.items.filter(expense => {
  if (filteredYear > 0 && expense.date.getFullYear().toString() !== filteredYear) {
    return false;
  }
  if (filteredMonth < 12 && expense.date.getMonth().toString() !== filteredMonth) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```